# Smarty, functions and variables inside strings from database

Tags: php, smarty

I want to be able to parse Smarty functions within strings retrived from my database.

Example:
`$var = 'Something {"modifed by function"|smarty_function} more string';
$this->smarty->assign("var", $var);`

I want the Smarty {$var} to run the function, but it doesnt. How can i make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it using `fetch()` (in case you want to save output to variable) and adding `string:` to your string.

For example running:

```
$string = 'Something {"modifed by function"|smarty_function} more string';
echo $smarty->fetch('string:'.$string);
```

when you have modifier:

```
function smarty_modifier_smarty_function($string)
{
    return strtoupper($string);
}
```

will give you:

> Something MODIFED BY FUNCTION more string

output.

You can also use `display()` method:

```
$string = 'Something {"modifed by function"|smarty_function} more string';
$smarty->display('string:'.$string);
```

and it will give you the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something inside your controller that's for Smarty. In other words, PHP would need to do this and pass it to the template. You can't just assign a Smarty string inside PHP for parsing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can include a variable as if it were a template like this.

```
{include file="eval:$var"}
```

Comment: Your answer seems incomplete, can you give an example?